# request.isUserInRole() does not work in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, weblogic11g

I have a spring MVC application. I am using weblogic basic user authentication where I have a user role created on weblogic server and user added to that role. 
User is able to login to the application and application enters the default method of the controller class. In this method I have following logic to check if user exists in the group which does not work.  It should satisfy  if condition but it goes to else.

```
 if(request.isUserInRole("GROUP_MANAGER"))
  {
        // do something

  }else
  {
        // do something
  }
```

My web.xml has following

```
     <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>App</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>     
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint> 
    <role-name>GROUP_MANAGER</role-name> 
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>  

  <security-role>
    <role-name>GROUP_MANAGER</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

My weblogic.xml has following

```
     <wls:security-role-assignment>
        <wls:role-name>GROUP_MANAGER</wls:role-name>
        <wls:externally-defined/>
</wls:security-role-assignment>
```

Please help